# Using a Griffin Powermate as a foot operated left mouse click

Tags: windows-7, mouse, administrator, mouse-click, griffin-powermate

I thought my career in programming would ruin my wrist until I set up one of these bad boys as a foot operated left mouse click.

[image: The Griffin PowerMate]

It works well enough, but it won't execute a left click if I'm holding down shift or control on the keyboard. Neither will it execute left clicks if I'm operating a program as an administrator (for example: Visual Studio).

What are some solutions/workarounds to these issues? I've tried running the PowerMate software as administrator, but it still won't work while running applications as admin.

The ultimate goal is less wrist fatigue (any and all tips welcome ;). I know I can achieve that by clicking with the mouse as little as possible.

Comment: The simplest way would be to write software to support it.  Its possible of course the drivers are written not to support this behavior.

Comment: Are you saying that being able to add this functionality is dependent on the drivers? Could I possibly write supplemental software that would get the job done? I suppose changing the drivers themselves are out of the question.

Comment: Input devices like this, simply replicate in most cases, an input device ( keyboard, mouse ). You could verify what is being exactly by writting a small application to compare the differences between a `SHIFT Left Mouse Click` and a `Shift + Pedal Toggle` I am going to guess they won't be the same. Have you contacted Griffin about this problem?.  A mouse driver or software for the mouse i suppose does indeed define what keyboard command should happen when SHIFT and Left Mouse Click is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Found your old post and wiring something out of an Arduino acting as a generic hui device shouldn’t be too hard.  That way you could get an actual footswitch there, or 10.

I’m working in the live sound industry and those tiny tactile encoders they put in the PowerMate will not tolerate being stomped on for a long time.  They break after not so long just because of fingers.

With an arduino you could even manage to use anything as a sensor.  Just a wooden board with a piezo stuck on it could become a trigger.  Tap your foot for a left click (ok, no drag and drop possible there, but you see what I mean).